# xmlstarlet format

Tags: xmlstarlet

I am trying to format a xml file using xmlstarlet but I don't want to create a new xml file.

I tried this

```
xmlstarlet fo --inplace --indent-tab --omit-decl project_00.xml
```

but the parameter `--inplace` is not allowed to the `fo` (format) command.

Does anyone know how I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fo subcommand always writes to stdout, so you would have to patch xmlstarlet.

Otherwise

```
TMP_XML=$(mktemp)
xmlstarlet fo --indent-tab --omit-decl project_00.xml > "$TMP_XML"
mv "$TMP_XML" project_00.xml
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot. It was simple... I have to familiarize me with shell script.

Answer (score 6):

You could use this one liner

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -O  project_00.xml
```

Reference
http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139594320